# How do you debug internal Firefox javascript modules?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

Much of Firefox is implemented as javascript modules in javascript in files like: resource://gre/modules/AddonManager.jsm  How can you get a javascript debugger to set breakpoints in this code as the Firefox starts up?

(Most Firefox documentation and web searches refer to javascript debugging for the 'end user' web page scripts, not the internal scripts)

Comment: I think you can go to `about:debugging` and click debug next to an addon. I usually dont debug those with break points, just with `console.log`

Comment: @Noitidart, thanks, I need to debug/explore earlier in the operation of Firefox than when the add-on finally gets called  (for this need and debugging FF in general.  -- I didn't see how about:debugging worked.  I check the 'enable debugging' and clicked the 'Debug' button near my addon , but the javascript debugger didn't show any indication of working when I used by addon.

Answer (score 0):

> On Firefox 19 or later, it's possible to use the built-in JS debugger
> on the browser itself.  Go to about:config and set the following two
> prefs:
>
> devtools.chrome.enabled: true,
>
> devtools.debugger.remote-enabled: true
>
> After you restart the browser, you can access the Browser Debugger
> through Tools > Web Developer > Browser Toolbox. (Note that before
> Firefox 28, this was labeled "Browser Debugger" and only the debugger
> was available, not the whole toolbox.)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Debugging/Debugging_JavaScript